# Soliciting Beta Testers

Tags: joomla-3.x, development

Is there any web site or forum that's OK to solicit beta testers for a Joomla Plugin? I'm developing a calendar plugin and I'd like to get more people to test it. If it seems like this is a redundant post, it's because StackExchange rejected my one-sentence post.

Comment: Not too sure, perhaps https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/joomla-dev-general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some posible options:

- The Joomla! [Forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewforum.php?f=48)
- The Community in [Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/103500906097842801714)
- The Joomla! group in [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/joomlanospam)
- The Official Joomla! Users Group in [Linked In](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/52867)

Regards.

Comment: Lets not forget [Joomla's Chat Room on Stack Exchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14071/joomla) ;)